# 4 cards alignment with respect to the circle at the center of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, frontend

I have four cards of same with and their height can vary based upon the content inside it. I want to align the cards with respect to the circle at the center of the container, whose height and width is 138px. Here is the picture layout that I want to achieve :-
[image]

I want to achieve the given layout. Currently I am using the absolute positioning and giving the fixed value to the top, right, bottom, left values of the respective four cards. But the content inside the card can be increased or decreased from the backend. So if the card content is increased the said layout is breaking, I want this layout to be same irrespective of the card content and height but the position near the circle should be same. Here is what I have implemented. Is there any way to achieve the said layout which is dynamic and positioned with respect to the circle.

HTML and  css:

```css
    .testi {
        max-width: 1280px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        height: 1500px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    
    }
    
    .circle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 138px;
        height: 138px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00aeef 0%, #0095da 25%, #0071b4 50%, #0061af 75%, #293996 100%);
    }
    
    .inner-circle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    /* testimonial card style */

    .testimonial-card {
        position: absolute;
        width: 406px;
        max-height: 888px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch;
        gap: 32px;
        padding: 48px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    
    
    .testimonial-card {
        width: 406px;
        max-height: 888px;
        flex-grow: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: stretch;
        gap: 32px;
        padding: 48px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .testimonial-card-title {
        font-family: Gotham;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.44;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        color: #757584;
    }

    .testimonial-person-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .testimonial-card-image {
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .person-detail {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .person-name {
        height: 20px;
        font-family: Gotham;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.43;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        color: #263746;
    }

    .person-des {
        font-family: Gotham;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.43;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        color: #263746;
    }

    .location-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .Location {
    width: 24px;
       height: 24px;
       flex-grow: 0;
       object-fit: contain;
    }

    .office-title {
        width: 106px;
        font-family: Gotham;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-stretch: normal;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 1.43;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-align: left;
        color: #263746;
    }

    /* End of testimonial-card style */

    .card1 {
        top: 115px;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .card2 {
        top: 115px;
        right: 145px;
    }
    
    .card3 {
        bottom: 165px;
        left: 115px;
    }
    
    .card4 {
        bottom: 165px;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
                    <div class="inner-circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
                    <div class="testimonial-card card1">
                        <div class="testimonial-card-title">
                            “This will be my third year at HUB working on the Human Resources team. As a military spouse, it can be hard to find a role that allows you to advance in your career, but also be there for your service member and family. HUB has granted me that, and so much more. My supervisor understands my situation and continuously supports me through it. When my husband deployed, my team rallied around me and celebrated with us when he returned. The Military Veterans & Military Family Voices group is a special place where anyone who is in the military community has instant comradery and support. What I am impressed with most is this group’s ability to actively listen to each other’s experiences and draw lessons on how to be a better advocate from it.”
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
                            <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                            <div class="person-detail">
                                <div  class="person-name">
                                    Glenn Agoncillo
                                </div>
                                <div class="person-des">
                                    Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
                                </div>
                                <div class="location-container">
                                    <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
                                    <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
                                </div>
        
                            </div>
        
                          </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-card card2">
                        <div class="testimonial-card-title">
                            “My passion is to give a voice to those who are underrepresented. As someone who fits into that category, I’m passionate about bringing awareness and opportunities to those who look like me and making allies out of those who don’t. HUB Black Inclusion Network does just that; it provides a safe and collaborative space for this while enhancing HUB’s inclusive culture and expanding our diversity footprint.”
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
                            <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                            <div class="person-detail">
                                <div  class="person-name">
                                    Glenn Agoncillo
                                </div>
                                <div class="person-des">
                                    Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
                                </div>
                                <div class="location-container">
                                    <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
                                    <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
                                </div>
        
                            </div>
        
                          </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-card card3">
                        <div class="testimonial-card-title">
                            “In order for HUB to thrive, we must embrace diversity and inclusion so we can continue to serve all our clients from all walks of life. HUB Women Network (HWN) provides a forum to help women of all levels and diversity at HUB be able to Engage, Empower, and Excel in all aspects of their lives. Through monthly calls, webinars, and panel discussions, we create a safe space for women to speak freely, engage with others and exchange insights.”
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
                            <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                            <div class="person-detail">
                                <div  class="person-name">
                                    Glenn Agoncillo
                                </div>
                                <div class="person-des">
                                    Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
                                </div>
                                <div class="location-container">
                                    <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
                                    <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
                                </div>
        
                            </div>
        
                          </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="testimonial-card card4">
                        <div class="testimonial-card-title">
                            “This year I’ll be celebrating 6 years working at HUB in the Risk Services Division and I am very proud to be involved in all the different opportunities to create a culture of diversity, equity, and inclusion in all regions. Now there are several ways to get involved as a leader, a participant, and an ambassador to do our part here at HUB. The Asian American/Pacific Islander community is a special place for me, to feel the genuine connection I have with other colleagues because of our similar cultural background. I am Chinese and Filipino, and this community provides me a natural way to support, connect and identify with other peers all while working at HUB.”
                        </div>
                        <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
                            <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
                            <div class="person-detail">
                                <div  class="person-name">
                                    Glenn Agoncillo
                                </div>
                                <div class="person-des">
                                    Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
                                </div>
                                <div class="location-container">
                                    <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
                                    <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
                                </div>
        
                            </div>
        
                          </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                
              </div>
```

Attaching the original UI here :[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to align the cards with respect to the circle at the center of the container" ? In your picture, it's not clear how exactly the cards position is related to the circle (especially when the cards can change height)

Comment: Hi @Kokodoko, as you can see the ending of the 1st card should be position to the horizontal center of the circle towards top, and the starting  of the 4th card should be from the horizontal center of the circle from bottom, and there is a padding of 48px of the cards, now the 2nd and 3rd card should be aligned in a way that the ending left and right side of the circle will be a straight vertical line to the padding start of the circle. you can all see the UI create by me in full page, that is how the UI should look, but if i increase the content of any of the cards, it will break the layout

Comment: Instead of positioning the cards in absolute, you could `align-self` them if the parent was a grid. Top ones would be `align-self: start`, bottom ones `end`, etc...

Comment: if it has align self: start, then the 2nd cards will be starting from top, which is not what I require.

Comment: Could you clarify how the top right and bottom left are to be aligned as your image hasn’t got them aligned to a circle diameter.

Comment: hi @AHaworth I have added the main UI, pls look it, the cards are positioned with respect to the circle at the center

Comment: The only problem of this image is that there is no design for small screens. If you use absolute positioning it will break on smaller screens.

Comment: Hi @Kokodoko, in small screen this 4 cards will form a carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is breaking probably because top 2 has to be possitioned based on `bottom` and bottom 2 based on `top`, since content is added to the end of container.

Absolute positioning should be more then enough for this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: centeR;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: fit-content;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card:nth-last-child(1) {
    left: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.card:nth-last-child(2) {
    background: red;
    bottom: 100px;
}

.card:nth-last-child(3) {
    background: blue;
    left: -100px;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.card:nth-last-child(4) {
    background: brown;
    top: 100px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="card">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorems with the re Ipsum passages, ay unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheetsnd more recently with desktop publishing softwgalley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survivedy unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets not only ktop publishfive ceny unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheetsy unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheetsturies, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="card">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknowsed in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letrass wstting industry. Loe 1960s ws  with the re 1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shrem Ipsum has been the industry'ised in the 1960s ws  with the rewstting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bektop publishen the industry'ised in the 1960s ws  with the reset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing softwand more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="card">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting iktop publishndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'ised in the 1960s wstting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'ised in thee 1960s ws  with the re 1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shs e 1960s ws  with the re 1960s ws  with etraset shs etraset shs etraset shs the reith te 1960s ws  with the re 1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shhe release of Letraset shwstting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry'ised in the 1960s ws  with the re 1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset sheets s with the re Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="card">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has sur1960s ws  with the reith the relektop publishase of Letraset shhe release of Letraset shwstting indu1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shhe release of Letraset shwstting indu1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shhe release of Letraset shwstting indu1960s ws  with the reith the release of Letraset shhe release of Letraset shwstting induvived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue come from the `absolute` positioning.
By using grid, you should be able to position each card relative to the center of the grid. Then, you just need to center the circle.

Note that you still have to translate the card to have this shift you're looking for, a simple `transform: translate(x, y);` will do.

Let me know if that answer your question:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: end;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  width: 138px;
  height: 138px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00aeef 0%, #0095da 25%, #0071b4 50%, #0061af 75%, #293996 100%);
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.testimonial-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}


/* testimonial card style */

.testimonial-card {
  width: 406px;
  max-height: 888px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 32px;
  padding: 48px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  align-self: end;
}

.card2 {
  align-self: end;
}

.card3 {
  align-self: start;
}

.card4 {
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial-card card1">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card2">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card3">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card4">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cumque enim earum, libero ipsam dolor. Alias, deleniti autem illum quas ducimus veniam, optio ipsa a mollitia quasi ipsam laudantium inventore!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <div class="inner-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning absolute will work - with a few alterations to the way you position the cards.

This snippet removes flex from the container, but keeps the way you have centered the circle.

It positions each of the cards in relation to the relevant side that is to be aligned with a circle diameter and uses translateX/Y to position it a bit away from the circle (for convenience it uses the diameter of the circle to do this, of course add more if you want it to be greater).

To help adjust things in future if required the snippet does the calculations based on the diameter of the circle being a CSS variable --d.

```html
<style>
  .testi {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100vw;
    --d: 138px;
    --r: calc(var(--d) / 2);
  }
  
  .circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: var(--d);
    height: var(--d);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00aeef 0%, #0095da 25%, #0071b4 50%, #0061af 75%, #293996 100%);
  }
  
  .inner-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: calc(80 / 138 * var(--d));
    height: calc(80 / 138 * var(--d));
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  /* testimonial card style */
  
  .testimonial-card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 406px;
    max-height: 888px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 32px;
    padding: 48px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .testimonial-card {
    width: 406px;
    max-height: 888px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    gap: 32px;
    padding: 48px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .testimonial-card-title {
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.44;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #757584;
  }
  
  .testimonial-person-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .testimonial-card-image {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .person-detail {
    width: 250px;
  }
  
  .person-name {
    height: 20px;
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #263746;
  }
  
  .person-des {
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #263746;
  }
  
  .location-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .Location {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  
  .office-title {
    width: 106px;
    font-family: Gotham;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.43;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #263746;
  }
  /* End of testimonial-card style */
  
  .card1 {
    right: calc(50% - var(--d));
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--d)));
  }
  
  .card2 {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translateY(calc(-1 * var(--d)));
  }
  
  .card3 {
    right: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(var(--d));
  }
  
  .card4 {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateX(var(--d));
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="inner-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="testimonial-card card1">
      <div class="testimonial-card-title">
        “This will be my third year at HUB working on the Human Resources team. As a military spouse, it can be hard to find a role that allows you to advance in your career, but also be there for your service member and family. HUB has granted me that, and so
        much more. My supervisor understands my situation and continuously supports me through it. When my husband deployed, my team rallied around me and celebrated with us when he returned. The Military Veterans & Military Family Voices group is a special
        place where anyone who is in the military community has instant comradery and support. What I am impressed with most is this group’s ability to actively listen to each other’s experiences and draw lessons on how to be a better advocate from it.”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
        <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
        <div class="person-detail">
          <div class="person-name">
            Glenn Agoncillo
          </div>
          <div class="person-des">
            Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
          </div>
          <div class="location-container">
            <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
            <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card2">
      <div class="testimonial-card-title">
        “My passion is to give a voice to those who are underrepresented. As someone who fits into that category, I’m passionate about bringing awareness and opportunities to those who look like me and making allies out of those who don’t. HUB Black Inclusion
        Network does just that; it provides a safe and collaborative space for this while enhancing HUB’s inclusive culture and expanding our diversity footprint.”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
        <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
        <div class="person-detail">
          <div class="person-name">
            Glenn Agoncillo
          </div>
          <div class="person-des">
            Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
          </div>
          <div class="location-container">
            <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
            <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card3">
      <div class="testimonial-card-title">
        “In order for HUB to thrive, we must embrace diversity and inclusion so we can continue to serve all our clients from all walks of life. HUB Women Network (HWN) provides a forum to help women of all levels and diversity at HUB be able to Engage, Empower,
        and Excel in all aspects of their lives. Through monthly calls, webinars, and panel discussions, we create a safe space for women to speak freely, engage with others and exchange insights.”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
        <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
        <div class="person-detail">
          <div class="person-name">
            Glenn Agoncillo
          </div>
          <div class="person-des">
            Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
          </div>
          <div class="location-container">
            <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
            <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-card card4">
      <div class="testimonial-card-title">
        “This year I’ll be celebrating 6 years working at HUB in the Risk Services Division and I am very proud to be involved in all the different opportunities to create a culture of diversity, equity, and inclusion in all regions. Now there are several ways
        to get involved as a leader, a participant, and an ambassador to do our part here at HUB. The Asian American/Pacific Islander community is a special place for me, to feel the genuine connection I have with other colleagues because of our similar
        cultural background. I am Chinese and Filipino, and this community provides me a natural way to support, connect and identify with other peers all while working at HUB.”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial-person-wrapper">
        <img class="testimonial-card-image" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532712938310-34cb3982ef74?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3d2e8a2039c06dd26db977fe6ac6186a">
        <div class="person-detail">
          <div class="person-name">
            Glenn Agoncillo
          </div>
          <div class="person-des">
            Vice President of Constituent Experience and Co-chair of HUB Pride (LGBT) Voices
          </div>
          <div class="location-container">
            <img src="Location.png" class="Location" alt="location-icon">
            <div class="office-title">Office Location</div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

You may like to consider making the dimensions of the cards also into a CSS variable, perhaps related to the width of the viewport, so that the whole thing becomes more responsive.